# how to update specific column name based on condition pgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I want to update the value of specific column based on the id.

This is what I am trying

```
update my_table
    set my_date=now(),
        case _id
            when _id = id_1 then id_1_number = id_1_number + 1
            when _id = id_2 then id_2_number= id_2_number + 1
         where user_id = _user_id;
```

but this is showing

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "case"
LINE 36:      case _id
              ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 950
```

is there any way to update the value of specific column based on the condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CASE expression can't contain an assignment, you need to use the result of the expression to assign the value. And you need one for each column

```
update my_table
   set my_date = now(), 
       id_1_number = case when _id = id_1 then id_1_number + 1 else id_1_number end,
       id_2_number = case when _id = id_2 then id_2_number + 1 else id_2_number end
where user_id = _user_id;
```